# Manually installing provisioning profile in XCode?

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile

XCode for some reason refuse to download freshly created provisioning profile.

[image]

I downloaded it manually from iTunes Connect, but how do I install it now? (Moving to its folder doesn't work).

Any tips?

Comment: Double-click the manually downloaded file

Answer (score 3):

I too struggled when Xcode didn't even show me the regenerated profile in the accounts section and i was not able to find anywhere how to manually import. Then after a lot of trials i found the solution.

Manually Download you provisioning Profile from developer.apple.com, then right-click on the provisioning profile file and choose "Open with..." XCode. Profile will automatically be added and will be reflected as downloaded in your screenshot above.

Comment: this did it for me! Can also double click on the profile and it should automatically add it to Xcode

Comment: Nothing happens when I do this. It just shows the XCode window. What should I expect?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on macOS, not sure about other platforms:  Open an Xcode project for an app that you will use with the provisioning profile.  Select the app target and the "Signing and Capabilities" tab.  Open the Provisioning Profile pop-up menu, and select the menu item "Import Profile...".  Select your downloaded profile file, and then you should be good to go.